# How do I set fish as the default shell?

Tags: command-line, fish

Is there a way to set fish as the default shell in ubuntu netbook remix? I put in my .bashrc to run fish, which works fine, but ubuntu recognizes it as fish running inside bash, which means that when I try to close the shell it warns me that a task is still running.

It doesn't pop up as a new application, so I can't pin it to my bar like a normal app.

Comment: From the official FAQ: [How do I make fish my default shell?](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#faq-default)

Answer (score 240, accepted):

You can set fish as your default shell by running

```sh
chsh -s $(which fish)
```

To do so for another user, just add the username at the end of the command, and use `sudo`.

Then log out and back in.

(To set it back to `bash`, you need to use Fish syntax of course, like this `chsh -s (which bash)`)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. It doesn't give an error, but it just doesn't seem to work, even if I just open a new tab. Any thoughts?

Comment: You may have to log out & back in - I just tried it on a clean virtual machine & it worked.

Comment: How do you set it back?

Comment: That should be `chsh -s /bin/bash`.

Comment: Don't accidentally run this command with `sudo` or you'll change the root shell instead.

Comment: Or `chsh -s (which fish)` from inside fish.

Comment: What's the default shell for Linux Mint 18.3 cinnamon, i.e. if I want to go back to how it was...

Comment: Does this work without doing https://askubuntu.com/a/1025536/476086 ?

Answer (score 40):

```
usermod -s /usr/bin/fish username
```

Must be run as root though.

This will change the shell permanently for the specified user.

Comment: I know it's not Ubuntu, but I wanted to comment: I was on CentOS, and I was getting an `Authentication Failed` error trying to change the shell with a non-root user and after extensively searching to try and figure it out, this was the only thing that worked. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it will work on most unix flavours that have usermod and fish for a shell, or change the shell to whatever flavour you wish

Comment: I did that and now the terminal doesn't start anymore. I get "There was an error creating the child process for this terminal", "Failed to execute child process "/usr/bin/fish" (Input/output error)". How can I undo that?

Comment: Issue the same command as root but use bash instead of fish as the shell.

Comment: @ptkato In case you are running Ubuntu via WSL, go to Powershell and run `wsl ~ -e bash`, this will open up bash. Now, to set bash as the default shell, enter `sudo usermod -s usr/bin/fish <username>`.

Answer (score 29):

I just added the line `fish` to the end of my `.bashrc`.

Comment: That's the simplest and best solution, IMO ;)

Comment: Sorry, but its not efficient. :)
It will load your fish shell but on top of your bash running.

Comment: Why does bash need to be efficient? @M.JunaidSalaat

Comment: From the first glance this seems like a dirty hack, but after a while of using my pc with fish set as the default shell with chsh I came back to this solution. Some programs assume that you're using bash and will crash because of using bash syntax on fish. So far I faced such problems in i3wm and matlab.

Comment: @codenamejames: It's not that bash needs to be efficient, or that those few milliseconds matter, but it's a case of nothing to lose, so why not do it correct? Especially here where we are giving advice to other people. We should know better

Comment: I see this a bad practice for "defaulting" a shell. Bash and Fish have different syntaxes. Bash for example declare variables as `VAR=some_var` and fish as `set VAR some_var`. There is no `.bashrc` for fish (https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html). I expect close terminal when run `exit` command. Running fish from bash, after `exit` command I got back to bash terminal.

Comment: This will break your system. The desktop can not be displayed normally and the scp command won't work neither.

Comment: @M.JunaidSalaat By using [exec](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/exec.1p.html) (which is POSIX compliant), the *command* argument will replace the shell (i.e. will be executed with `execve()` system call). Bash will no longer be running. Environment variables are preserved, though.

Answer (score 24):

I agree with the `chsh` is the correct answer. However:

If you run `chsh` and get error

```
/usr/local/bin/fish: non-standard shell
```

simply add the fish binary location to `/etc/shells`.

Found [here](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4073162).

Comment: This is necessary to do on macOS Mojave.

Answer (score 11):

In `/etc/shells`, add `/usr/local/bin/fish`:

```
# List of acceptable shells for chpass(1).
# Ftpd will not allow users to connect who are not using
# one of these shells.

/bin/bash
/bin/csh
/bin/ksh
/bin/sh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/zsh
/usr/local/bin/fish
```

Then `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/fish`.

Comment: This works on MacOS Big Sur

Comment: @dorian it says I can't edit the file. how can I edit it?

Comment: @mesqueeb you need to `sudo nano /etc/shells` for instance if you want to edit with nano

Comment: It's `/opt/homebrew/bin/fish` now on my system