# Why is my default shell from /etc/passwd not started by terminals in a Unity session?

Tags: command-line, login, gnome-terminal, fish

I'm trying to set fish as my default shell.  It's installed on the system through apt-get and is listed in `/etc/shells`:

```
> which fish
/usr/bin/fish
> grep fish /etc/shells
/usr/bin/fish
```

I used `chsh` to switch from Bash to fish:

```
> chsh -s /usr/bin/fish
```

And my default shell has been changed in `/etc/passwd`:

```
> grep "myusername" /etc/passwd
myusername:x:1000:1000:Oh Spite,,,:/home/myusername:/usr/bin/fish
```

Awesome.  Then I logged out and rebooted.  Login shells (e.g., virtual TTYs and SSH) now start fish.

And yet, when I start a terminal with either gnome-terminal or urxvt, a bash session is started.  Additionally, the `SHELL` variable is still set to `/bin/bash`.

Interestingly, Terminator *does* use fish as the default shell.  But even in that session `SHELL` is set to `/bin/bash`.  If I start urxvt from Terminator, urxvt starts a Bash session.

What else do I need to do to change my default shell to fish?

(See also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26439/how-do-i-set-fish-as-the-default-shell), but this is not a duplicate because I have followed those instructions *and* rebooted.  Many times now.)

Comment: Is your final target to start `fish` as the default shell for terminal ? also whats the output of `getent passwd myusername` now ?

Comment: @heemayl Yes, having fish as the default shell is my goal.  The output of `getent passwd myusername` is exactly the same as the `grep` output in the question (I forgot about `getent`.)

Comment: What happens if you login from the TTYs?

Comment: @muru Oh yes, I should have mentioned that login shells (virtual TTYs and ssh sessions) do start fish and `SHELL` is set to `/usr/bin/fish` in them.  It is non-login shells that start Bash (except for Terminator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most terminals (at least gnome-terminal, urxvt, and XTerm, for example) that are started within a desktop environment such as Unity will use the `SHELL` environment variable to select the shell when they are launched.

`SHELL` should automatically be set to your default shell listed in `/etc/passwd`, but the variable can be overwritten when you log in.  Make sure you have not set `SHELL=/bin/bash` or something similar in a file that will affect your entire desktop session.  Such files include:

- `~/.profile`
- `~/.pam_environment`
- `/etc/environment`
- maybe some other files edited by Ubuntu users less often, such as `/etc/profile`

Additionally if any scripts such as `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` are called by those other startup files and there is an `export SHELL=/bin/bash` line, that will also affect the entire desktop session.

---

I know it's acceptable/encouraged, but I still hate answering my own question.  Nevertheless, this may be of some use to someone in the future.  Thanks to @heemayl and @muru for helping me investigate.

Comment: Was `SHELL` overwritten by one of those files in your case?

Comment: @muru It was.  And me listing all of the options where it can happen is an attempt to be helpful to future readers, but also a smokescreen to try to cover my embarrassing oversight.

Comment: @ohspite, care to share _how_ or _why_ your SHELL was overwritten? No matter how "embarrassing" this is it might be helpful to know a circumstance where this happen

Answer (score 1):

To set `fish` as the default shell for `gnome-terminal`, from `gnome-terminal` go to :

```
Edit > Profile Preferences
```

then go to `Title and Command` tab, you will get :

[image: before]

Change it as :

[image: after]

Now whenever you start a new instance of `gnome-terminal`, `fish` will be started instead of `bash`.

Comment: Thanks heemays.  This would work for gnome-terminal, but I'm trying to set fish as the default shell for my user on the system, not for a particular application. In fact, I'm tempted just to put `exec fish` at the top of my Bash startup script, which would work for any terminal, but that shouldn't be necessary; I'm trying to figure out how to do it the proper way.

Comment: @ohspite Your login shell is set to `fish`, but some applications  may use `bash` ecxplicitely, you need to change manually for those..also note that there are differences between login and non-login shells anad the files they read while starting..your question does not seem properly directed now..could you please elaborate where/in what applications you are having problem with `fish` ?

Comment: Thanks for helping me focus the question.  I don't think each application needs to be set up independently; for example, `man urxvt` says by default the `SHELL` environment variable will be used.  Perhaps the narrower question is "why is SHELL not set to the value in /etc/passwd after logging in", but that's not my true question so I was trying to avoid an XY problem.