# How do I get WSL to start my login shell by default?

Tags: login, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" application always starts, well, bash. I have used `chsh` to set another shell as my login shell. How do I get WSL to start that shell instead?

Answer (score 4):

This is fixed in [a currently Insider-only build](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/816#issuecomment-301216901), with the new `wsl.exe` command:

> As of build 16188 when running bash.exe without arguments (or with the
>   ~ argument) bash will be launched as a login shell. The same is true
>   for the new wsl.exe binary (with the exception that wsl launches your
>   user's default shell as a login shell).

Prior to this, you'd have to edit the shortcut to add command-line parameters (such as `-c 'exec "$SHELL" -l'`):

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate more on this? I'm trying to run fish on start up but can't. Some details here https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/2199

Comment: As no one else has answered could you accept your answer?

Answer (score 2):

A bit of historical context for anyone attempting to add a new answer nowadays. This question was originally asked back in the dark-ages-of-early-WSL.  Back then:

- Ubuntu/WSL was known as "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows"
- It was launched via the `bash.exe` command
- It *always* launched the Bash shell

The `bash.exe` command was deprecated a while back and replaced with the `wsl.exe` command that @muru mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/922880/1165986).

Now, you can change your default/login shell to Fish (or typically any other shell) using the standard Ubuntu methods mentioned, for example, in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1025536/1165986).  In short:

- Make sure the shell is represented in your `/etc/shells`
- `chsh -s <path_to_shell>`
- Or typically, `chsh -d $(which fish)`

Answer (score -1):

To launch, e.g., fish in Ubuntu in WSL, set your target to

```
C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe --distribution Ubuntu --exec fish
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This really doesn't answer the question that was *asked*, which was how to change the login shell. Back in 2017 when this question was asked, Ubuntu/WSL was launched via the `bash.exe` command, and it always launched Bash. Now (and for quite a few years), the `wsl` command will launch whatever shell is set with `chsh` as [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/922880/1165986) mentioned was "coming soon" at the time. You can use the method you mention to do a "one time" launch of Fish, but changing the login shell requires another method.

Comment: Oh, okay. I was specifically looking for how to set the WSL starting shell from a launch target, and this seemed to be the most relevant question at the time.

Comment: That makes sense - Suggestion, though - This would be a good answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1161156/1165986).  I'd delete the answer here and post it there instead.  I'll help edit your answer there to be clear, since the original question there mentions `ubuntu.exe` rather than `wsl.exe`.