# How to run a command when launching WSL Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, scripts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can open `ubuntu.exe` using a `.bat` file by:

```
start ubuntu.exe
```

But I want to pass the parameter "./mnt/c/xxx.sh" to `ubuntu.exe`.

I.E. I want `ubuntu.exe` to launch a specific shell by using a `.bat` file, to ensure I don't have to open that particular shell every single time I open `ubuntu.exe`.

*Can anyone give me some suggestions?*

Comment: I close-voted for "unclear what your asking" as I don't understand a word of what you're talking about? `ubuntu.exe`? But could have voted for "Off-topic" as well because you tagged the question 14.04, which is EOL and thus unsupported here.

Comment: @pLumo, I think the OP is referring to the Ubuntu Shell on Windows 10.  "/mnt/c/...." gives the game away. :-p https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Comment: I see ... thanks ;; then it should be off-topic as it's not about Ubuntu but Windows.

Comment: I think they may be trying to do the equivalent of `/bin/bash -c "....."`.  I don't have a Windows machine handy to see if that's possible with WS4L.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I found the solution.

Comment: Yes, it's the Ubuntu Shell on Windows10.

Comment: @pLumo Windows Subsystem for Linux has been deemed on topic here via [discussion on meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15229/do-we-consider-ubuntu-on-windows-10-the-same-as-an-official-ubuntu-flavour-do) and community practice. Only version specific questions should be closed as EoL, though it's hard to tell what is a version-specific question and what is not. I'm with you on not understanding the question, but it looks like that's our fault (or more kindly, lack of experience with WSL).

Comment: Okay, I think I misunderstood a question or I'm still not sure. How to call ubuntu.exe from batch/.bat might be off-topic, something inside WSL on-topic. I don't think that the meta discussion exactly covers it. Imo it's a corner case.

Comment: **Edited!** Useful for anyone else wanting to do this!

Answer (score 4):

In the Ubuntu.exe help manual I found:

> **run < command line>**
>      Run the provided command line in the current working directory.
>      If no command line is provided, the default shell is launched.

So in the .bat, I used:

```
start ubuntu.exe run /mnt/c/xxx.sh
```

It works well.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution!  **:-)** Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1161169/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions and answers in the future... **;-)**

Comment: Thanks Fabby! I reviewed your edits, it's exactly what I want to say. Next time I'll be more careful about the edits.

Comment: You're welcome!  That's what reviewers are for...  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Beside the answer that @Fabby mentioned, you can also run a command each time a shell is opened by adding your command at the end of the `~/.bashrc` file. That is assuming you are using bash.