# I use zsh as my regular user, but when I use root my shell is Bash. How can I use Zsh for root too?

Tags: bash, user-management, zsh

My Original question:

> When I run `sudo su` my `zsh` prompt changes back to Bash. How can I make Zsh the default shell for the root user?

My answer about duplicate :

The question about when a post is considered as duplicate is debating here : [Should questions be closed as duplicate only because of the helpfulness of answers?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14359/should-questions-be-closed-as-duplicate-only-because-of-the-helpfulness-of-answe)

I quote the first paragraph of the first answer :

> Most opinions I have seen about this say that questions are duplicates, not answers. Therefore, questions should only be closed as a duplicate when they are the same, not because the answer to one is also the answer to the other.

And then the first words after :

> I, however, disagree.

You are free to see the post to read the arguments of this user.

I personally, as "most opinions" think that questions are duplicates and no answers because i had never find an answer to my particular question with the post : [How do I set fish as the default shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26439/how-do-i-set-fish-as-the-default-shell)

And what a coincidence the user that i quoted is one of the users who marks my post as duplicate.

I tried to defend myself but probably in bad way. So please stop down vote my post and please understand that perhaps some people just want to extend already default shell to all users and others want make a particular shell to be default. This is not the same search and i think this can help the community.

Comment: Just use `root` instead of your own user name and `csh` instead of `fish`.

Comment: hi @DavidFoerster i think my question is legit and a bit different than the one you purpose. My question is about when we use root user to keep the same shell. My default shell is zsh but when i use root user it changed to ba. h . The first answer in the post you send me does not answer my question ... only the second ... and is for a different shell . My question got a right answer in first position . That's why i think my question is legit and could help some.

Comment: Ok, Thanks @Zanna you are really more  synthetic  than me :)

Comment: I think this is a Bad Idea. Many `root` owned scripts depend on `bash` features that don't work exactly the same as in `zsh`

Comment: It is absolutely a duplicate. Once you are logged in as root you run chsh and select zsh, exactly as written in the answers to the duplicate question.

Comment: different question,  different problem,   different voted solution and different result. Sad some experienced users comes and decided for others just to win reputation. Just let users choose which one suits for them.

Comment: Of course it's a duplicate. The actual user you want to change the shell for doesn't matter, the process is always the same: Either `usermod` or `chsh`. Think of this: if I have two users on my machine, `alice` and `bob`, and want to change their shell, then I would not ask the same question twice just because the usernames differ. The same is true for the user `root`.

Comment: Ok, I understand the process to resolve the issue is the same, but couldn't have the same answer for different reasons / questions ? That's why i though this post  is not really a duplicate, but i bow behind the community, you should have all reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set the shell for your root account

```
usermod -s /bin/zsh root
```

Will do the job

---

this changes the entry in the `/etc/passwd` file. They look sth. like this

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Where the last entry is the login shell. You can also edit the file manually.

---

Be careful to set it right. `usermod` will not check (and you will not be able to login as root):

```
usermod -s /bin/blargh root
sudo -i
sudo: /bin/blargh: command not found
```

For a saver way see the answer by @PerlDuck

Comment: Thanks  that is the right solution it works perfectly now

Answer (score 3):

Apart from `usermod` there is also the [`chsh` (*change shell*)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/chsh.1.html) utility. It has the advantage that a user can change his own shell without bothering the `root` user.

I remember it showing a little menu with the available shells and the user can pick one but my current installation does *not* show such a menu. Perhaps because I don't have additional shells installed (besides bash).

```
pduck@myhost:~> chsh
Password: 
Changing the login shell for pduck
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Login Shell [/bin/bash]:
```

Comment: I did not know `chsh`. I think it is a good option, as it does some checking. (does the file exist, is it executable)