# How to disable close terminal warning?

Tags: command-line, fish

When I use fish shell and try to close the terminal without exiting from fish, it gives me a warning before closing. How to get rid of the warning?

[image: screenshot of popup warning on terminal that states: Close this terminal? There is a still a process running in this terminal. CLosing the terminal will kill it.]

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a warning from the `gnome-terminal` and is independent of the shell you're using.

**According to other users, the following command will disable the warning:**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings confirm-close false
```

However, it will also disable the warning when there are other processes "still running" besides fish so it's kind of a tradeoff.

**To enable the warning again, run the following command:**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings confirm-close true
```

---

**Alternatively, if you normally use fish instead of bash, you can avoid this problem altogether by [setting your default shell to fish](https://askubuntu.com/a/26440/167115). To do so, use bash to run the following command:**

```
chsh -s $(which fish)
```

Close the terminal and open a new one or log out and log back in to apply the changes.

**To change the default shell back to bash, use fish to run the following command:**

```
chsh -s (which bash)
```

Again, log out and log back in or close the terminal and open a new one to apply the changes.

[Click here for different methods of setting fish as the default shell.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26439/how-do-i-set-fish-as-the-default-shell)